# Queue_free() runs immediately on start instead of on trigger

Tags: godot

In my game, I have a player sprite which has a collision area.

The grass in my game also has a collision shape.

The grass is supposed to have a effect when colliding with the player sprite, but, when I run the game, the grass immediately runs the effect and is gone.
When I comment out queue_free(), the grass has a effect as it should (on collision)

```
extends Node2D

func create_grass_effect():
        var GrassEffect = load("res://Effects/GrassEffect.tscn")
        var grassEffect = GrassEffect.instance()
        var world = get_tree().current_scene
        world.add_child(grassEffect)
        grassEffect.global_position = global_position

func _on_Hurtbox_area_entered(area):
    create_grass_effect()
    queue_free()
    print('test')
```

Console output:

test

test

test

test

(each test for every grass node)

If needed, I can provide more code from the game.

Keep in mind, I am a new game developer, this is from a tutorial.

[image]

Art from Heartbeast https://www.youtube.com/c/uheartbeast

Edit:

I consoled the variable area and this is what I got:

```
[Area2D:1364]
[Area2D:1344]
[Area2D:1372]
[Area2D:1368]
[Area2D:1339]
[Area2D:1339]
[Area2D:1339]
[Area2D:1339]
[Area2D:1339]
[Area2D:1339]
[Area2D:1339]
[Area2D:1339]
[Area2D:1339]
[Area2D:1339]
```

1339 is when grass is touched in game and the numbers at the start are run automatically when game is run

Another edit:

When disabling collision in the player, the grass still does it's effect and queues free

Edit 3:

Disabling collision in grass causes the grass to behave as it should except you can't collide with it

Comment: Unfortunately, there's not a lot to go on here, but my first question would be: Are the four grass tiles colliding with each other's hurtboxes and tripping? Does it work if there's only one grass tile?

Comment: Aside from the possibility that they could be colliding with each other, it also posible that the problem is the code that instance them. If you are instancing them from script, then adding them as children, then giving them position, they could register the collision before you gave them position. Also, if the intention is that the player character will trigger then, you can check if the area that entered is from the player character. In fact, put a break point and see what area enters, that should clear up what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why but changing the signal to `body_shape_entered` from `area_entered` seemed to work.