# What is TileMap:1373

Tags: godot

I'm following a tutorial series by Heartbeast.

My grass area2D is being collided with TileMap:1373 in the beginning

```
extends Node2D

func create_grass_effect():
        var GrassEffect = load("res://Effects/GrassEffect.tscn")
        var grassEffect = GrassEffect.instance()
        var world = get_tree().current_scene
        world.add_child(grassEffect)
        grassEffect.global_position = global_position

func _on_Hurtbox_area_entered(area):
    pass

func _on_Hurtbox_body_shape_entered(body_id, body, body_shape, local_shape):
    print(body_id, body, body_shape, local_shape)
```

```
func _on_Hurtbox_body_shape_entered(body_id, body, body_shape, local_shape):
    print(body_id, body, body_shape, local_shape)
```

console

```
1373[TileMap:1373]100
1373[TileMap:1373]100
1373[TileMap:1373]110
```

Despite moving all tile maps out of the way for the two small green grasses:
[image]

When I tell the script to queue_free() on `_on_Hurtbox_area_entered`:
[image]

Flipping the code doesn't work because when I have this code:

```
extends Node2D

func create_grass_effect():
        var GrassEffect = load("res://Effects/GrassEffect.tscn")
        var grassEffect = GrassEffect.instance()
        var world = get_tree().current_scene
        grassEffect.global_position = global_position
        world.add_child(grassEffect)

func _on_Hurtbox_area_entered(area):
    queue_free()

func _on_Hurtbox_body_shape_entered(body_id, body, body_shape, local_shape):
    print(body_id, body, body_shape, local_shape)
```

The grass disapears anyways.

So the problem must be due to the signal or queue_free()

EDITTTTT:

I was looking and I think this solved my problem:

> The question isn't entirely clear on what you want to trigger the signal, but I assume you want it to fire when the player enters the area. The docs for area_entered say:

```
Emitted when another area enters.
```

> The player is a PhysicsBody, not an Area. Use body_entered instead:

```
Emitted when a physics body enters.

The body argument can either be a PhysicsBody2D or a TileMap instance (while TileMaps are not physics body themselves, they register their tiles with collision shapes as a virtual physics body).
```

So I guess the signal is wrong then...

Comment: `TileMap:137` does not appear anywhere in your post.

Comment: You are printing a `TileMap`. The output is telling you that it is a `TileMap`, and has some id number. Which `TileMap` is it? I don't know. Run your game, go to the scene panel, on the remote tab, and see what id do your `TileMap`s have. Some of them must match the id you are getting. Using breakpoints will make it easier.

Comment: @Theraot I found that it was the cliff tile but then when I took all the tiles out there was no log but the grass still disapeared despite not telling me it collideded with anything...

Comment: Does flipping these two lines work: `world.add_child(grassEffect)`, `grassEffect.global_position = global_position`? [I mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70283185/queue-free-runs-immediately-on-start-instead-of-on-trigger#comment124242158_70283185) that setting the position after adding the node is a bad idea. I don't know if you tried that. As per the object disappearing without registering a collision, if you have a call to `queue_free`, put a breakpoint there. Figure out how it was called. And if none hit, then we need to look for some other code removing it.

Comment: @Theraot Check my question again

Comment: If put `breakpoint` instead of `queue_free()` or `pass`, does it not fire? You said you found it was the cliff, but even after removing the cliff the grass disappeared, even without logging a collision. Here is an idea that might just work. Declare a `queue_free` function, so that it hides Godot's one. And inside of this fake `queue_free` put `breakpoint`. Then don't call `queue_free` from the collision, to see if it is called from somewhere else. I guess it could also be `free` instead of `queue_free`. Or `remove_child` on the parent. You could make fakes for those too.

Comment: You edit is from the following answer, correct? https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/178334/10408 So, is it fixed with that change? - I still don't understand how what you said before happened "the grass still disapeared despite not telling me it collideded with anything" - but, hey, if it is fixed, it is fixed.

Comment: @Theraot I fixed my problem check the answer

Answer (score 0):

The grass is touching itself and causing it self to queue_free()

I solved the problem by putting the grasses apart from each other.